# Swift: Sticky Header in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift4

I'm newly in iOS developing, I try to create an app that contain a UI such as:

[image: this]

By using [GSKStretchyHeaderView](https://github.com/gskbyte/GSKStretchyHeaderView) in swift and read me of it but I cannot configure it properly , are there any tutorial of how to use it in Swift or any snippet of code of how to achieve that?

Comment: GSKStretchyHeaderView, seems to be working good with Swift, what is the issue?

Comment: @SebitasSg are there any example of how to use it?

Comment: I'm quite busy atm, I can create an example project for the next weekend.

Comment: @SebitasSg I wait U